# 401. "str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, linux, http-status-code-401

The code below produces these errors:

'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
Please help me understand what I did wrong. I made sure un and pwd are correct

```
user = "un"
password = 'pwd'

datanodes = ["https://server040:25000/"]

for i, datanode in enumerate(datanodes):
    print("Checking {0}: {1}".format(i, datanode))
    try:
        print "trying"
        response = requests.get(datanode + "queries?json",auth=(user, 
password), verify='certs.pem')
        print response
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        print data
        if data["num_waiting_queries"] > 0:
            print(data["num_waiting_queries"])
            for in_flight_query in data["in_flight_queries"]:
                if in_flight_query["waiting"] is True and 
in_flight_query['state'] == "FINISHED":
                    cancel_url = datanode + "cancel_query?query_id=
{}".format(in_flight_query['query_id'])
                    print(cancel_url)

    except IOError as ioe:
        print ioe
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I have tried both json.load(reponse) and json.loads(response.read())

Comment: response.json() could work too

Comment: The `requests.Response` object doesn't have a `read()` method. Have you looked at [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response)?

Comment: @PRMoureu <Response [401]>
No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @kindall json.load(response) did not work either

Comment: I didn't suggest using `json.load(response)` so... I mean, look at the documentation and see what you're trying to get out? A first step might be printing `response.content` to see if you're getting back what you think you're getting? The error you get when trying @PRMoureu's suggestion implies that you think you're getting JSON but you're not.

Comment: Also, it looks like HTTP response code 401 is involved... this implies that you're not properly authorized, which is why you're not getting the JSON you want.

Comment: user and pass are good, what about `certs.pem` ?

Comment: cert.pem is good

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the issues by adding HTTPDigestAuth and changing data = json.loads(response.read()) to data = response.json()